Corporate account posted AI generated ad as a "question"
This user just posted a "question" that was actually an AI-generated ad for their company's services. They deleted the question before I could finish reporting it but I'm wondering if action should be taken against this user? The user's profile description is this:

We are a team of enthusiasts reaching out to corporates and offering them Indoor & outdoor activities for their employees. Our activities delivers fun yet impactful team building activities, which include team development, corporate values inculcation and team leadership. Our activities are designed to encourage team bonding, team cohesiveness, team motivation, team performance development.

Here is their deleted post. For those that can't access deleted posts, here's the content of their deleted post:

[Post content redacted on behalf of community]


(Converting my comment to an answer to give this thread some closure)
Thank you for raising this.
The user did not delete their own question. It was automatically deleted by the Community Bot thanks to users like you flagging and reporting. The account has been blocked from posting again.
